# Having trouble with mod_rewrite on my Laravel app

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ubuntu, laravel

Currently, I can only access links on my Laravel project if they are in the form of `domain.com/index.php/somepage`.  I want to be able to be able to get access with a URL like `domain.com/somepage`.  On my local Windows machine it is working fine. My server is on Ubuntu and running Apache 2.4.6 and the `rewrite` module was enabled via `a2enmod rewrite`.  My `.htaccess` is the default one that ships with Laravel:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I've also tried the alternate in the Laravel docs both with and without the `<IfModule>`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I realize this has been asked before but I still can seem to get it working with other examples that I've seen.  I'm guessing it must be some Apache configuration that I don't have set.

Comment: You didn't tell what do you want and facing the trouble for ?

Comment: @SheikhHeera thanks, I added that in.  The question has already been answered though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you make sure that allowoverides all was in your httpd config?

That sounds like your issue.

Comment: That was it.  I just switched the setting in the appropriate directory in my `apache2.conf` file.